# How to set a Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I would like to know how to get the regular expression of the following text:

```
XXXXXX[Some Same Text # AAAA-NNNN]XXXXXX
```

Where:

```
'X' can vary any text: Alfa, numerical or symbols (The X can have 0 to infinite characters and it is NOT obligatory).
'A' Alfa uppercase text (The Alfa has exactly 4 uppercase letters and it is obligatory).
'N' Numbers (The N have exactly 4 numbers and it is obligatory).
'Some Same text' has exactly the same text always and it is obligatory.
'[,],#,-' will always be there in that same possition and it is obligatory.
```

I have a preg_match that goes:

```
*[Some Same Text([A-Z]{4})-([0-9]{4})]*
```

And it isn't seem to be working.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

`.` matches any character, and `*` means 0..infinity.
When using `[` and `]` you need to escape them. Try this:

```
.*\[Some Same Text # ([A-Z]{4})-([0-9]{4})\].*
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, but now I got this warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '*' do you know what it could be?

Comment: You're probably not calling preg_match like it expects. You need delimiters, like so: `preg_match('/(.*)\[Some Same Text # ([A-Z]{4})-([0-9]{4})(.*)/', ...`

Comment: Yes, I really dont know what it was though I got it to work through Jason's code. Thank you so much for your help dave and Jason! Best regards! and sorry because I was pretty new to regular expressions :P

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `'/^.*\[Some Same Text\s#\s[A-Z]{4}-\d{4}\].*$/'`. As Tested:

```
if(preg_match('/^.*\[Some Same Text\s#\s[A-Z]{4}-\d{4}\].*$/', 'XXXXXX[Some Same Text # AAAA-4444]XXXXXX'))echo 1;
```